# Stairway handrail needs to be lower than the wall mounting

Tags: stairs, brackets, railing, handrail

I want to install a stairway handrail, but the lower part of the wall is covered by an old marble panelling that cannot be drilled.  So the only place I can attach brackets to the wall is above this panel (about 44 inches above the stair level).  That is about 6 inches too high for the rail. So I am looking for some solution that will allow me to have the rail be 6 inches BELOW where the brackets attach to the wall.  We have tried installing regular curved brackets upside down.  This does get the rail to the right height, but it looks ridiculous (it looks like someone installed a handrail upside down).   Does anyone know of a bracket that is actually designed for this purpose - ie, sits above the rail but attaches below it?  Or any other kind of solution?  Thanks!

[image: As found stairwell]

Comment: Why do you think marble cannot be drilled? I have drilled holes in stone, glass and marble... Or are you scared of drilling in the wrong place?

Comment: Hi - a contractor who has worked with similar buildings told us that its very likely to crack and not to risk it.

Comment: Does the marble panels stick out from the upper wall(is there a small ledge)?  How wide are the stairs?

Comment: Well, I'd hate to be on the drill when the marble cracks, but I too have made zillions (it seems!) of holes in various stone. I've had cracks when I'm really close to the edge, but the diamond grit mini holesaws (Milwaukee, among others, makes them) have been pretty good. And fyi, marble is usually way the heck easier than porcelain.

Comment: I have to agree I have drilled quite a few holes in Victorian era marble and a fresh bit or core saw with a slow speed usually works the older the marble the better as it is usually better quality. If there are a lot of veins only use a core saw (like a hole saw with carbide bits at the end) a twist type will fracture veins in the marble.

Comment: lets respect your decision not to drill in marble, so you need metal hinges/stripes extensions

Comment: Hpw about this bracket https://www.lowes.com/pd/Deckorators-3-in-Offset-Bracket-Textured-White/5001785227?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-lum-_-bng-_-PLA_LUM_265_Composite-Decking-Railing-Lattice-_-5001785227-_-Online-_-0-_-0&msclkid=b0dff86309a2168a36869ab12aaf6561&gclid=b0dff86309a2168a36869ab12aaf6561&gclsrc=3p.ds

Comment: Can you share a pic? I'm dreaming up a nice wrought iron sort of thing that goes all the way from the bottom (stringer) to the lip of the marble, with a bracket (of course) to hold the handrail. Make it a feature...

Comment: @Ruskes  - thanks, but I get "Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.lowes.com/pd/Deckorators-3-in-Offset-Bracket-Textured-White/5001785227?" on this server.
Reference #18.57ca4d68.1658041899.110891b4"  - apparently I dont have sufficiently high security clearance for this product!

Comment: @Aloysius Defenestrate  I would be happy to post a picture but dont see a way to upload one here - is there?

Comment: Sorry for that, try the search therm : Deckorators  6-in White Aluminum Rail Bracket
Item #3768709
Model #389229 at Lowes

Comment: Post a link to a hosting site (imjur, postimage, etc) and we’ll edit it into your question. I think new users are limited in what they can do.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate thanks!  it is at this link https://imgur.com/a/9G3Pgse  This is the current status, using a conventional bracket mounted upside down.

Comment: After seeing the picture, I get how it might not look ideal. I'm not sure I have a better idea, though. Maybe somebody else will chime in.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate OK thanks anyway and thanks very much for posting the picture.  Its a protected Bauhaus building from the early 20's by a quite well known architect and so am reluctant to "vandalize" it with something that looks so off.  But local codes now require a handrail so...

Comment: I think it looks fine.... How exactly do you envision brackets that come from above but attach below?

Comment: @19565 I assumed there might be something sort of S shaped for these kind of situations - ie, curves down under the railing and then turns back up to attach from underneath.  But I have not managed to find anything like that on Google.